# Google Chrome: network tab -> http headers

Tags: google-chrome, http-headers

Stupid question.
Where is the rightnav in my browser where I can see the HTTP headers and responses?
Didn't it used to be there?

[image]

I need it to analyse my results of my Ajax requests. 
Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- Open the element inspector (right click)
- Refresh the page (now you will see all the http request)
- Click on the single request to see header req/res

Comment: Wow I don't know where my thoughts were... I double clicked on the php files so many times to open it in a new tab, that I forgot to single click it. Can't believe this. Thanks!